# Clustered vs NonClustered Index for date range query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query in mySql:

```
SELECT field1
FROM table1
WHERE tdate > '2018-6-01' OR (tdate BETWEEN '2015-4-07' AND 2016-6-07);
```

What would improve the query performance more, an index on `tdate` or a covering index on `(tdate, field1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create index with [included columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-2017):

> Redesign nonclustered indexes with a large index key size so that only columns used for searching and lookups are key columns. Make all other columns that cover the query into nonkey columns. **In this way, you will have all columns needed to cover the query, but the index key itself is small and efficient.**

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx_name ON tab_name(tdate) INCLUDE (field1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to include a column in mysql?

Comment: @YeltForman I don't think that it is possible with MySQL. You could create normal composite index (tdata, field1)